# Matlab: invalid mex file library not loaded

Tags: matlab, mex, dylib, rpath

I have created a mex function (more specifically, using CUDA)

the compilation was successful, and I got a `mex` file `zMul.mexmaci64`

but on the execution, matlab reported an error:

```
Invalid MEX-file '/Users/zlw/Documents/MATLAB/lowComplexity/cbased/matMulGPU/zMul.mexmaci64':
dlopen(/Users/zlw/Documents/MATLAB/lowComplexity/cbased/matMulGPU/zMul.mexmaci64, 1): 
Library not loaded: @rpath/libcublas.6.0.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/zlw/Documents/MATLAB/lowComplexity/cbased/matMulGPU/zMul.mexmaci64
Reason: image not found
```

What should I do do solve it?

**additional info**

1. setting the environment vars (PATH,LD_LIBRARY_PATH,DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH) in Matlab and in `.bash_profile` doesn't work for me
2. I'm pretty sure that the environment vars are set correctly because when I created an alias to the `dylib` file, Matlab detected it, tried to load it, but failed with message:`no suitable image found`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `otool -L` in both Matlab and UNIX console.

In Matlab:

```
!otool -L /path/to/zMul.mexmaci64
```

In UNIX console:

```
otool -L /path/to/zMul.mexmaci64
```

Try to find the difference between them. If there is a difference in dependency, that is probably breaking the MEX binary. You might need to apply the same technique for the dependent dylib objects recursively. Typically, enforcing the one appearing in UNIX console using `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` solves the problem.

Another possibility is the C++ runtime compatibility. If you're using OS X Mavericks, you should check that your MEX command is using `libc++` but not `libstdc++` in `mexopts.sh`. Below is my configuration example in `mexopts.sh`:

```
CC='clang'
CXX='clang++'
SDKROOT='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/'
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.9'
CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -Dchar16_t=uint16_t"
CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -DCHAR16_T"
CXXLIBS="$MLIBS -lc++"
```

Answer (score 0):

This post might help: http://www.seaandsailor.com/matlab-xcode6.html

It was easier than I thought. Just replace all 10.x with your OS X version and add `-Dchar16_t=UINT16_T` to `CLIBS` in `mexopts.sh` file.